# test_conceal.vim failed: strange, why is that?

Tags: conceal

Here is the `make test` result:

```
-------------------------------
Executed:  3788 Tests
 Skipped:    57 Tests
  FAILED:     1 Tests


Failures: 
    From test_conceal.vim:
    Found errors in Test_conceal_two_windows():
    Run 1:
    command line..script /home/asuka/Downloads/code/vim/src/testdir/runtest.vim[468]..function RunTheTest[39]..Test_conceal_two_windows[80]..VerifyScreenDump line 58: See dump file difference: call term_dumpdiff("testdir/failed/Test_conceal_two_windows_09v.dump", "testdir/dumps/Test_conceal_two_windows_09v.dump"); difference in line 12: "|t|w|o| @1|h|e|r|e| @3> @61"
    Run 2:
    command line..script /home/asuka/Downloads/code/vim/src/testdir/runtest.vim[502]..function RunTheTest[39]..Test_conceal_two_windows[80]..VerifyScreenDump line 58: See dump file difference: call term_dumpdiff("testdir/failed/Test_conceal_two_windows_09v.dump", "testdir/dumps/Test_conceal_two_windows_09v.dump"); difference in line 12: "|t|w|o| @1|h|e|r|e| @3> @61"
    Run 3:
    command line..script /home/asuka/Downloads/code/vim/src/testdir/runtest.vim[502]..function RunTheTest[39]..Test_conceal_two_windows[80]..VerifyScreenDump line 58: See dump file difference: call term_dumpdiff("testdir/failed/Test_conceal_two_windows_09v.dump", "testdir/dumps/Test_conceal_two_windows_09v.dump"); difference in line 12: "|t|w|o| @1|h|e|r|e| @3> @61"
    Flaky test failed too often, giving up

TEST FAILURE
make[1]: *** [Makefile:49: report] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/asuka/Downloads/code/vim/src/testdir'
make: *** [Makefile:2257: scripttests] Error 2
```

I configured with `--disable-gui`, and the source was just fetched down so it should be the newest version.

Comment: Some tests fail in an inconsistent manner.  You can re-run the test with this shell command: `vim -u NONE -S runtest.vim test_conceal.vim conceal_two_windows` (you need to be in the `src/testdir/` directory).  Try in an xterm terminal, with a "default" geometry (80 columns x 24 lines).  Then, read the file `test.log` or `messages`.  Remove the files before running the test again.

Comment: Your first error is raised [from here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/10ccfb2a17e736ace054b19dc712544b4e961671/src/testdir/test_conceal.vim#L89).  Can you post the contents of `testdir/failed/Test_conceal_two_windows_09v.dump`?

Comment: It seems the issue comes from the cursor position, which in your case is unexpectedly further away from where it should be.  I remember reporting a few similar issues in the past (github issue #3625, #4931, #5214).  Maybe you've found yet another similar bug.  What's the name of the terminal?  What is its geometry?  What's the value of `$TERM`?  How do you configure Vim before running the compilation?

Comment: Also, can you post a screenshot showing where the cursor is drawn after running [this shell command](https://0x0.st/-Xj-.txt)?

Comment: @user938271 Thank you!! Sorry that wasted your time, I refetched the code and build again and this test passed - at the first build I firstly `make reconfig` then `./configure --disable-gui` then `make` (maybe I did something else I don't remember), and I believe the extra `make reconfig` make something conficted - and the initial build folder was removed by me, therefore I can't provide the information for you. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1LTS default `gnome-terminal` 80x24, and `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a vim problem, but caused by incorrect building procedure. I refetched the code and build again and this test passed - at the first build I firstly `make reconfig` then `./configure --disable-gui` then `make` (maybe I did something else I don't remember). I believe the extra `make reconfig` made something conficted.